# "Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'."

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm getting the above error when I try to build my program.

```
[  +53 ms] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +59 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/beta
[        ] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] beta
[        ] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +17 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 3b309bda072a6b326e8aa4591a5836af600923ce
[        ] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 2 weeks ago
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +67 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v0.7.3-0-g3b309bda0
[ +683 ms] executing: /usr/bin/defaults read /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info CFBundleShortVersionString
[ +118 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/defaults read /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info CFBundleShortVersionString
[        ] 3.1
[ +154 ms] executing: /Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +25 ms] Exit code 0 from: /Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
[  +22 ms] executing: idevice_id -h
[ +889 ms] /usr/bin/xcrun simctl list --json devices
[ +185 ms] More than one device connected; please specify a device with the '-d <deviceId>' flag, or use '-d all' to act on all devices.
[   +7 ms] /Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +79 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +10 ms] Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
[   +2 ms] iPhone 8 Plus             • 8109F9A5-6CE8-4DB9-AB93-E93E07F25F34 • ios         • iOS 11.3 (simulator)
[  +32 ms] "flutter run" took 2,111ms.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)                   
#1      RunCommand.validateCommand(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:258:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:334:11) <asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:290:33) <asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29) <asynchronous suspension>
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:281:20)
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194:27) <asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:347:21) <asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29) <asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:303:19) <asynchronous suspension>
#20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:29)
#21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109:11)
#23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:211:18)
#24     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:59:20) <asynchronous suspension>
#25     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29) <asynchronous suspension>
#26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#28     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#29     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#30     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18) <asynchronous suspension>
#31     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:42:24) <asynchronous suspension>
#32     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#33     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:52:9) <asynchronous suspension>
#34     main (file:///Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#35     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#36     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

Here's the output from flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.7.3 at /Users/Me/MyApp/flutter
    • Framework revision 3b309bda07 (2 weeks ago), 2018-08-28 12:39:24 -0700
    • Engine revision af42b6dc95
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.3.1, Build version 9E501
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.2

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 25.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.18.0

[✓] Connected devices (2 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554                        • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • iPhone 8 Plus             • 8109F9A5-6CE8-4DB9-AB93-E93E07F25F34 • ios         • iOS 11.3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

Thanks!

edit: I forgot to mention that this problem is the same if I use flutter_test, or build_runner v. 0.10.2 . I read something about flutter_test having a bug causing this.  Doesn't seem to have been fixed in Dart 2.1.0

edit 2: Günter correctly pointed out that the error in the title doesn't actually show in the body I placed.  That is because, as I have discovered, this is a gradle issue, and not a flutter issue.  So when I try to run directly I get the issue (that is below) but when I do it `flutter run -v` I get the stack I previously pasted.

```
MacBook-Pro-3:MyApp Me$ flutter run -d all
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                       3.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                    3.8s
Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf".
Error building assets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 473

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Me/MyApp/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
10.1s
Gradle build failed: 1
```

Comment: The error in the question title is not part of the error output. Can you please ensure the error output in the question is the complete output of you get in the console?

Comment: Well that was silly!  Apologies.  Editing to insert and explain why that's the case.

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873122/execution-failed-for-task-appflutterbuilddebug?rq=1 with the same error message.

Comment: I saw that one, but the guy answered his own question, and the answer wasn't really specific. Maybe I just misunderstood, but I didn't get exactly what environmental variables he believed needed to be updated.  Obviously that can be project specific.  Are there any known environmental variables needed that go with the dart 2.1.0 release?

Comment: `Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "ios/Flutter/flutter_assets/fonts/MyFlutterApp.ttf".
` look weird. Do you have such a line in `pubspec.yaml`?

Comment: I do, but I don't remember putting it there (that isn't to say I didn't).  I just commented it out to see what happened and gradle built.  Hopefully that doesn't break anything else.  :)

Comment: The line doesn't make much sense and I think it's safe to remove.

Comment: Commenting that out seemed to fix the issue, and nothing is broken(so far).  I actually have an old question that appears related to the exact same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995661/flutter-code-extension-not-installed-but-its-been-installed-for-months). I'm just going to keep this font file out until something breaks. So thank you!  Do you want to write the answer, so I can give you credit for it?